# Find value of a functional equation

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Find $f(x)$ such that
$$2 f(n) + \frac{1}{3}f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = 12.$$
Can anybody suggest me a way to solve this kind of functional equations?

Comment: Does $f$ have to have some properties? Like continuity, differentiability, analyticity?

Comment: A trivial solution is $f\left(x\right)=\frac{36}{7}$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $f\left({\frac1n}\right)$ in terms of $f(n)$:
$$f\left({\frac1n}\right)=36-6f(n)$$
This is true for all $n\ne0$, so
$$f(n)=36-6f\left({\frac1n}\right)$$
Now let $a=f(n)$ and $b=f\left({\frac1n}\right)$, then solve linear system of equations. You will get that $f(x)$ is constant function
$$f(x)=\frac{36}7$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: I didn't understand how you got $f(x)=\frac{36}{7}$. Would you please explain it a bit more.

Comment: Let $a=f(n)$ and $b=f(1/n)$, then you have linear system of equations: $a=36-6b$ and $b=36-6a$, can you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

If we set, for any $x>0$, $f(x)=g(\log x)$, then $g$ is a solution of:
$$ 2 g(m) + \frac{1}{3}g(-m) = 12, \tag{1}$$
so we may take any $g$ such that $g(0)=\frac{36}{7}$, define it over $\mathbb{R}^+$ as we like then take:
$$ g(-m)=36-6g(m) $$
to define $g$ over $\mathbb{R}^-$.